# How to send a user-friendly error message on invalid datatypes for a POST?

Tags: c#, rest, validation, controller

The data is being validated correctly in the below code, but I would like to send back a more user-friendly error message than just returning a 500 if the data formatting is bad.

```
public class PostData
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public string MakeAWish([FromBody] PostData data)
{
    return "Happy BirthDay!";
}
```

The following value works fine.
`{ "dateOfBirth" : "1980-01-01" }`

The value below obviously does not.
`{ "dateOfBirth" : "1980" }`

How can I send back a user friendly message when the `dateOfBirth` is formatted incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set DateOfBirth to be a string. Then have another property that is the DateTime, i.e. DateOfBirthDT.

When the user submits the string DateOfBirth you can use DateTime.TryParse() to test if the string value can parse to a valid DateTime value, if not you can return a friendly error.

For example:

```
public class PostData
{
    public string DateOfBirth {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateOfBirthDT {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public string MakeAWish([FromBody] PostData data)
{
    if(DateTime.TryParse(data.DateOfBirth, out DateTime dob)) {
        data.DateOfBirthDT = dob;
        return "success";
    }else {
        return "Please post a valid date";
    }
}
```